# Is it always optimal to evenly split search space in Rényi-Ulam game?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose that we want to find one of finitely many elements (called **pivot**) by asking binary questions (one after the other) of which for at most $e$ we might get an incorrect answer and our goal is to minimize the number of questions needed in the worst case. This is known as the Rényi-Ulam game, for more basic info, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam%27s_game). For more info see the [Pelc survey](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397501003036) and [Cicalese's book](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-3-642-17326-4).

After some questions have been asked, we can classify the elements depending on how many answers must be incorrect if the given element is the pivot. If this number is greater than $e$ then the given element cannot be the pivot, while in every other case it can be, so our goal is to have at most one element for which at most $e$ lies are possible. The **state** is the vector that gives the number of elements in each class, e.g., $(x_0,\ldots,x_e)$, so our goal is to have $\sum_i x_i=1$. A question can be also represented by a vector $(q_0,\ldots,q_e)$ which describes for how many elements from each class the answer would be YES.

Suppose after some questions we are in a state $(2x_0,\ldots,2x_e)$. Is it possible that the even splitting question $(x_0,\ldots,x_e)$ is not optimal, i.e., there is another question which leads to a faster solution?

I have already asked some experts, like Katona and Cicalese, and they did not know the answer.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the expected number of questions until there is only one possible pivot, or are you minimizing the maximum number of questions required?

Comment: Nice question! Do you know that even splitting is optimal when $e = 1$? (@DouglasZare: in the literature I am familiar with, the aim is always to minimize the maximum number of questions required.)

Comment: @Douglas: Yes, I had in mind minimizing the maximum, I have added it to the question. In this model even splitting is optimal for $e=1$ (see e.g. http://math.iit.edu/~rellis/papers/9how.pdf). If we want to minimize the expected number, then I would not be surprised if the answer was negative already for $e=1$ (although it still holds for $e=0$).

Comment: I wrote a program to check, and in small examples (up to $52$ elements, with up to $3$ lies allowed) the even split is optimal.

Comment: @Douglas: Wow, thanks. Although I really think that counterexamples can be galactic in these kind of questions, like here: http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/1995/1995-219-230.pdf

Comment: I was interested in the qualitative behavior. For example, the best plays from the position $(2,2,54)$ are $(2,0,18),(1,2,21),(1,1,27),(1,0,33),(0,2,36)$. From $(4,72,0)$ the best plays are $(4,28,0),(3,32,0),(2,36,0),(1,40,0),(0,44,0)$. From $(4,0,108)$ the only best play is $(2,0,54)$. Those are chosen so that adding two more positions to the largest "pile" would increase the number of guesses required.

Comment: @Douglas: I am not sure I understand what you wrote, these positions seem far from critical to me. Maybe your notation is different from the usual? Could you please give some smaller example?

Comment: What do you mean by critical? I'm confused that you say that the interesting examples should be much larger but you want me to give much smaller examples. Could you give examples in your notation that you think are interesting?

Comment: @Douglas: So for example $(0,0,2^n)$ is critical for any $n$. Usually the interesting examples are of the form $(0,k,2^n-k(n+1))$. These are all critical if $k\le 2$ or much smaller than $n$. So this means that for example $(0,2,50)$ can be solved with $6$ queries.

Comment: I agree that $(0,2,50)$ can be solved in $6$ guesses but $(0,2,52)$ requires $7$. $(2,2,54)$ requires $7$ guesses while $(2,2,56)$ requires $8$. $(4,72,0)$ requires $10$ guesses, as does $(4,72,8)$, while $(4,74,0)$ requires $11$.

Comment: Douglas: Oh, I'm sorry, I have confused plays with positions, what you wrote must be all correct.

Comment: I think one can prove something like that fixing $(x_0,...,x_{e-1})$, for large enough $x_e$, an even split is as good as any other guess, by finding the right linear weights. If so, the interesting cases should be where $x_e$ is small.

Comment: Douglas: Yes, I am sure that this is true.